# How to replace the root certificate for Sitecore 9?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, xconnect

On our local and DEV environment (Sitecore 9.0.1 and Commerce 9) we need to replace the root certificate with a new one, therefore all "child" certificates need to be recreated and replaced. Is there a recommended way to do that or at least an approach.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I use these two PowerShell scripts to generate new certificates for Sitecore Commerce (if they was expired):

Generate SelfSignedCertificate for specific DnsName:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -FriendlyName "domain.dev.local" `
-DnsName "domain.dev.local" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" `
-NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)
```

Generate new PfxCertificate:

```
$CertificateStore = "cert:\\Localmachine\\My"
$CertificateDnsName = "identity.server"
$CertificateFriendlyName = "Sitecore Identity Server"
$CertificatePassword = "sitecore"
$pfxPath = "c:\certificates\$CertificateDnsName.pfx"
$certificate = New-SelfSignedCertificate `
-Subject $CertificateDnsName `
-DnsName $CertificateDnsName `
-KeyAlgorithm RSA `
-KeyLength 2048 `
-NotBefore (Get-Date) `
-NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10) `
-CertStoreLocation $CertificateStore `
-FriendlyName $CertificateFriendlyName `
-HashAlgorithm SHA256 `
-KeyUsage DigitalSignature, KeyEncipherment, DataEncipherment `
-KeySpec Signature `
-TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3")
$certificatePath = $CertificateStore + "\" + $certificate.Thumbprint
$pfxPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $CertificatePassword -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $certificatePath -FilePath $pfxPath -Password $pfxPassword
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $pfxPath -CertStoreLocation $CertificateStore -Password $pfxPassword -Exportable
```

After that you need to replace manually thumbprints from old to new in all configs.